# jquery mouseenter doesn't work on 'a' element, works fine on h3

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter

I have (I believe)a very simple problem, but can't figure out what is wrong. the code will tell everything:

```
$(".all-products h3").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings('p').slideDown(200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings('p').slideUp(500);
});
```

and this is html:

```
<a title="xxx" href="#">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
    <p>description</p>
    <h3>header3</h3>
</a>
```

This one works fine, but why doesn't it work when I replace in jquery the h3  with a, so it **doesnt work this way** below:

```
$(".all-products a").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).siblings('p').slideDown(200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings('p').slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: I hope I included all necessary information. I didn't find the rest of the code related with a problem. I believe the 'a' thing is wrong. Or maybe it can't be applied to a? no idea. A is set display:block;

Comment: Where is HTML for `all-products` class?

Comment: everything is here at the mo: http://cabins.tucado.com/ all sorted now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you are using siblings.

Try this:

```
$(".all-products a").mouseenter(function(){
          $('p', this).slideDown(200);
           }).mouseleave(function() {
          $('p', this).slideUp(500);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` is not a sibling of `p`, it is the parent of `p`.  Try using `.children('p')` or `.find('p')` instead (the former is more specific).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".all-products a").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('p').slideDown(200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('p').slideUp(500);
});
```

Siblings of a would exist at the same level in the DOM. In your case you want to .find() the elements or call children(). either way.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would seem the major problem is that that `p` element is not sibling to the `a`.  You would need to replace `siblings()` with `children()`